# Creating a PDF with custom values

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, printing

I am creating an iPad application. In this I have a form,and I need to fill the form with my app. I have some text boxes to enter the data. And when I click on the preview button, I want to display the entered values at the correct locations in the form. And it should display as a PDF form.  And also I am thinking about taking print of the form. 
How can I implement that? Please share your ideas.
Thanks :)

Comment: What will be your effort then?

Comment: @Sarah Effort? I am not asking anyone to create an app for me. I just asking for some thoughts. As this is my first time that i am creating an iPad app. There should be some experienced persons those who are done this kind of apps already. Is that a big mistake??

Comment: no. its not. But...anyways,you can try uitableview with custom cell with uitextfield.

Comment: @Sarah thanks. I am just afraid about the part where, how can I show the entered values on a form. Should that display as PDF or UIImageview? And how it is possible to display the data at the correct positions in the form?

Answer (score 1):

[Quartz2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) has all the functions for your PDF needs.

Comment: thanks, am I not sure how can I implement this, let me make a try :)